# is it possible to use same .ppk file fore more than one EC2 Instances?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to connect to multiple EC2 instances using same .ppk File?

From my understanding we need one PPK file per EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your question, it appears that you are using Windows computers to access Linux computers. PPK files are used by PuTTY to provide SSH access.

When a Linux instance is launched using the standard Amazon Linux AMI (and also some other AMIs), the selected public keypair will be automatically copied to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

You can the ssh into the instance by providing the private keypair (stored in the `.ppk` file). The Linux system will check that your private keypair matches the public keypair stored in the `authorized_keys` file and will permit the login.

Thus, you can use the same keypair for any number of EC2 instances.

However, it is good security practice to replace this keypair with a personal keypair or connect the instance to a directory service (LDAP or Active Directory). Basically, you should implement whatever security practice has been chosen by your company. Ask your security staff and System Administrators for advice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes It is possible. When you create new instance, you should use existed key for this instances